# Why is this DateTime error thrown when reading a char(1) DB field into string property, with no dates involved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just started getting this error today. Only one user is having this error.

> Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

I can recreate the error locally, but stepping through the debugger the error is thrown on a line that has nothing to do with dates or times. In the code a custom DAL queries an Oracle database and returns an OdbcDataReader, which is then iterated to populate a domain object. The database will have one or more records for each user. The exception is thrown when reading a `char` field into a `string` property. The code looks like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var program = new MyDomainObject();
    program.Code = reader["code"].ToString();
    program.Year = reader["year"].ToString();
    program.Title = reader["title"].ToString();
    program.Status = reader["status"].ToString();  <-- thrown on this line
    ... etc, then append the domain object to an IList and repeat
}
```

The `status` field is a non-nullable `char(1)` field in the database. Example status codes are 'A', 'B', 'Q', 'W', etc. I extracted the query and ran it directly against the database for that user and it works perfectly, so the issue is in the above code somehow. There are three date fields in that table that are used in this code, but the error is not thrown on any of those lines, and besides there is a null check for the one field that can be null. So I just don't see why this is happening here.

9,000 users since we launched the app a few days ago and this is the only error of this kind so far. Any ideas why this would be thrown here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that is the line of code that has the error? What is the next line?

Comment: If your db columns are string type (char, nchar, varchar, etc) try reader.GetString([column name]). Otherwise you should make your properties of the same type as your db columns and call the corresponding GetXXX([column name]).

Comment: wrap it in a try/catch and see if you can find the stack track, plus look at all innerException value of the exception object.  You might also try expanding that line as much as possible.  Try putting reader["status"] into it's own variable.  Then on a new line try calling the .ToString() and assigning it to a new string variable.  Then try assigning "A" to program.Status etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
program.Status = reader["status"].ToString();
```

is never, ever going to throw that exception. There's probably some mismatch between the line number reported in the exception and the source code you're looking at. Maybe the source code you're reading is different from what was deployed.

I'd look for a nearby line that does construct a date, and if not, one that reads a date. Somehow some data has gotten into your table that doesn't represent a valid date. Perhaps a user has some different culture setting and somehow their input made its way into a table. Like 30/4/2016 instead of 4/30/2016, or something along those lines.

The exception is good. When you find the cause I bet that it's going to accurately describe what's happening. It's just the indication of which line it's on that's misleading you.

I came across [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/660316?start=0&tstart=0). Does it help? It looks like this exact error has come up before when reading dates from an Oracle database. Oracle might allow storing an empty date in a manner which is unreadable to .NET.

Comment: Aha that's it! Thanks for the link. I formatted the date as it suggested and the date that shows as '1-AUG-93' in SQL Developer was actually '1-AUG-2593'! I'm sure the DBA will scratch his head on how that happened. Thanks!